# SEO lite {extra:desc} is not getting over ridden with the seo lite template description

Tags: seo-lite

I am using seo lite and it works fine with tag {extra:desc}.

But when I write in the seolite description in the template, it over writes the title and keywords but not the description. It overwrites if I dont use the tag {extra:desc}.

Can you please help me with this.

this is ma code ---

```
{if "{extra:desc}" !="" }

   <meta name='keywords' content='{meta_keywords}' />
  <link rel='canonical' href='{canonical_url}' />
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="CGYXJx34stuBq6Ahar-eFmhCJL-egrm533wopJONBoY" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta name="author" content="but.ae"/>
  <meta name='description' content="{exp:streeng characters="160" find="WHAT IS IT" replace=" "}{extra:desc}{/exp:streeng}" />

 <

 <title>{title}</title>

{if:else}

  <meta name='keywords' content='{meta_keywords}' />
  <link rel='canonical' href='{canonical_url}' />
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="CGYXJx34stuBq6Ahar-eFmhCJL-egrm533wopJONBoY" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta name="author" content="but.ae"/>
  <meta name='description' content="{meta_description}" />


 <title>The Future Build</title>
{/if}
```

Hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested the user was helped over here:

https://getsatisfaction.com/addonbakery/topics/seo-lite-extra-desc-not-over-riding

Answer (score 1):

I found that I wanted my meta description to be populated with the following priority:

- Custom SEO Description in entry edit SEO Lite tab
- Extracted {extra:desc} value from my entry
- Fallback site-wide Default description set in SEO Lite settings

I couldn't find a way to do this with SEO Lite as it stands, so I decide to add a new variables that I could use in my SEO Lite template, `{default_description}`, which contains the SEO Lite default description. That way, I can compare to see if my {meta_description} is equal to that, and if so, use my fallback {extra:desc}.

I added the following code to mod.seo_lite.php

```
$vars[$this->tag_prefix.'default_description'] = htmlspecialchars($seolite_entry->default_description, ENT_QUOTES);
```

And in my SEO Lite Template, I have the following:

```
<meta property="default_description" content="{default_description}" />
{if meta_description == default_description && extra:desc != ' ...'}
    <meta property="og:description" content="{extra:desc}" />
    <meta name='description' content='{extra:desc}' />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="{extra:desc}">
{if:else}
    <meta property="og:description" content="{meta_description}" />
    <meta name='description' content='{meta_description}' />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="{meta_description}">
{/if}
```

Now, if I have set a SEO Description in my entry, that will be output. Otherwise, if {extra:desc} has a value, that will be used. And if neither of those is set, it uses my default site-wide description.

Hope this helps someone!